# Distinguish events from different button fields

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a `for` loop that creates ButtonFields with identical text values. I want to get a distinct event from each of those buttons, which tells me which index of the `for` loop created the button.  I don't want to create an anonymous class for each ButtonField.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't completely understand your question.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

If they are going one by one (that I'm assuming from your post) you could remember index of the first one in use next code in your `fieldChanged` method:

```
if (field instanceof ButtonField) {
   int buttonIndex = field.getManager().getFieldIndex(field) - zeroButtonInex;
}
```

Don't forget to assign `FieldChangeListener` to each of these buttons.

Or sure you could make your new class from `ButtonField` (could by anonymous) where you could save index and have getter for it.

Comment: The @HelpMeToHelpYou answer is more safe

Comment: Setting a cookie (any Java object) to each of the button and then checking the cookie on the fieldChange event is another option. Check setCookie() and related methods in API Documentation.

Comment: @Rupak I completely forgot about this functionality. Make an answer and I will vote for it!

Answer (score 3):

You have add the buttons to an array. I will give you an idea to try this:

```
private ButtonField buttonsObj[];
```

In your code before the `for` loop you know the number of buttons, so you can initialize the array length.

```
int size = 10;
buttonsObj = new ButtonFields[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    buttonsObj[i] = new ButtonFields["btn"];

    buttonsObj[i].setChangeListener(this);
    add(buttonsObj[i]);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if(field == buttonsObj[i]) {
            // you can trigger your event 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting a cookie (any Java object) to each of the button and then checking the cookie on the fieldChange event is another option. Check setCookie() and related methods in API Documentation.